# Symfony2 Hostname Routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes, subdomain

I'm using hostname routing dependent on subdomain.

What I want to do is have two separate routings. When I'm running off www.example.com, then it uses one routing file, and if any other subdomain such as subdomain1.example.com or subdomain2.examples (etc etc), then it runs off another routing file.

My routing is as follows (yml):

```
route_www:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing/www/routing.yml"
    host: www.%base_host%

route_sites:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing/sites/routing.yml"
```

Now this works to a point. I am using FOSUserBundle and I have all these routes in the route_sites, but www.example.com/register for example is still viewable as www is still valid for route_sites. Is there anyway possibly using regex, to prevent subdomain www from using the route_sites route.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

use a placeholder, then you can use regex in the requirments

Comment: Thanks for this, definitely the way to go. Just wasn't sure whether regex was good at matching strings that do 'not' contain a string, but it seems negative lookarounds work /^(?!www)/ I'll give this a try later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use webserver virtual hosts configuration and set ENV variable in it. Based on this env variable you can load different symfony 2 environment or even different app (but you can still easy reuse/share entity mapping files, codebase with symlinks). It can be helpfull if you don't want to load all bundles or share some parts of config/codes.